# What is the difference between vector<int> a , vector<int> a[n] and vector<int> a(n)?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, initialization, declaration

I just learnt about vectors and I'm confused about their use.

Please tell me what is the difference between:

```
vector<int> a;
```

,

```
vector<int> a[n];
```

and

```
vector<int> a(n);
```

Comment: Let me ask you, what is the difference between `int a`, and `int a[n]`, and `int a(n)` (last one isn't exactly the same but close enough for this exercise)?

Comment: @NathanOliver i know all others but what is int(a) ?

Comment: `int a(n)` creates an `int` with the value of `n`.  For a vector, `vector<int> a(n)`, creates a vector with `n` elements as the "value" of `a`.

Comment: `int (a);` is equivalent to `int a;` :) Joice of typo in question/comment :)

Comment: @NathanOliver it means ` vector <int>  a[n] ` will create "n" number of vectors of  "int" type. And ` vector <int>  a(n)` will create a vector with "n" number of elements of "int" type. Right?

Comment: @AnishVijay Yep.

Comment: @AnishVijay `vector<int> a[n]` -- ok I have to ask -- where did you find this declaration?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i accidentally used this in my program and it worked. lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vector<int> a;` declares an empty vector.

`vector<int> a[n];` declares an array containing `n` empty vectors.

`vector<int> a(n);` declares a vector containing `n` zeroes.

Bonus:

`vector<int> a{n};` declares a vector containing the single element `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> a;
```

Declaration of a `vector` of `int`s named `a`

```
vector<int> a[n];
```

Declaration of an `array` of `vector`s of `int`s named `a` with `n` elements.

```
vector<int> a(n);
```

Declaration of a `vector` of `int`s `a` initialized to `n` number of `0`s.